# Extracting specific phrases from a cell and echoing them in another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Longtime learner, first time poster here!

I was wondering if anyone knew how to extract specific data points (phrases) from a Google Sheets cell and echo them in another cell.

[image]

For instance, in my example I have Vehicle year/make/model/trim etc. All in my `B` column. I would like to be able to extract for instance the trim into it's own column.
So for instance I would need the formula to search for `XL`, `XLT`, and `STX` and if one of those is found, then echo that exact phrase out in another cell.

I would and can post a few things I have tried, but I honestly haven't gotten very close yet. Mostly ended up echoing out the complete cell value or `#NA`.

Also please note that the format for the original cell might change so an ideal solution would not rely on the information being sandwiched between two "known variables" but instead simply search for specific variables and echo those when found.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you're looking for are `REGEXMATCH` combined with `OR` and `IF`.
So IF will test three conditions (with `OR`) and then if `OR` returns a `TRUE` boolean, copy the cell's content, else do whatever.

```
=IF(or(REGEXMATCH(A1,"XL"),REGEXMATCH(A1,"XLT"),REGEXMATCH(A1,"STX")),A1,"no match")
```

Here's a way to do it with only one formula

```
ArrayFormula(IFS(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A5,"XL")),A1:A5,ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A5,"XLT")),A1:A5,ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A5,"STX")),A1:A5))
```

**EDIT :**
Here's a way to return the tested key :

```
       =ArrayFormula(
IF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"XL")),"XL ",)
&IF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"XLT ")),"XLT",)
&IF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"STX")),"STX",)
)
```

There's a condition for each "key" then it retuns it in case of a match. I used `&` to concatenate the result if case of multiples keys inside the data.

> Example : **"Sample with XL and XLT"** will return "XL XLT"

**Edit 2 :**

Same thing with `Regextract` to get rid of `IF`.

```
=ArrayFormula(ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6,"XL")))&"-"&ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6,"XLT")))&"-"&ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6,"STX"))))
```

Comment: Hey Paul, Thanks so much for your answer. So I just tried this and it looks to say essentially if=TRUE, copy entire cell. Would it be possible to essentially say if=TRUE, copy the variable that made it true (in this case like "XL" or "STX" as opposed to the entire contents of the cell?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes absolutely. I think there are multiples ways to do this, I'll try and edit this answer

Comment: @BrianL, I just edited the answer. This formula is ok when you have a small amount of variables/keys but can be boring to edit if you have a lot to test.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much for your help Paul! I really appreciate it!!